# Appium - Steps to use Appium Inspector with Android emulator on Windows

Tags: android, android-studio, appium

I want to use the Appium Inspector on Windows 7.
I want to use it with the example Android app `ApiDemo` and the Android emulator.

My question is: What steps do have I to do, to make this work?

I have installed:

1. Appium GUI
2. Android Studio with Android SDK
3. Java JDK

I have set the path variables.
I have configured an Android emulator by GUI.

- Do I have to install the app on this emulator?
- Do I have to build the app in a special way with Android Studio or can I simply use the delivered `ApiDemo.apk` for installation?
- Do I have to launch the emulator or is Appium Inspector doing this for me?

Thanks in advance!

Greets.

EDIT: This is what Android emulator is showing me.

[image]

Is this correct? Because nothing changes from here? What have I to do?

Answer (score 0):

Appium installs and launches the app, all u need to give the path of the apk u have in ur machine and emulator name in the desired capabilities,activity name

if its for java , use this code, to launch the app

```
public class sample{
    protected static AppiumDriver driver = null; 

       private static DesiredCapabilities capa = null;   


        public static void main(String[] args) {

            try{


                    File app = new File("D:/MobileAutomation/yourpath/appname.apk");

                    capa = new DesiredCapabilities();    
                    capa.setCapability("automationName","Appium"); 
                    capa.setCapability("platformName","Android");
                    capa.setCapability("deviceName","Android Emulator");
                    capa.setCapability("platformVersion","5.1");
                    capa.setCapability("newCommandTimeout","30");
                    capa.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
                    capa.setCapability("resetKeyboard", true);    
                    capa.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
                    capa.setCapability("appPackage", "com.yourapppackage name"); 
                    capa.setCapability("appActivity", "com.yourappactivity name");

                    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4731/wd/hub"), capa);
```

Answer (score 0):

*Suggestion* : You can go through some tutorials and sample code on using appium for automation. Just to answer the listed questions inlined as follow :

> Do I have to install the app on this emulator?

***No*** : The sample code similar to the one as shared by @karthick23 would do that on its own.

> Do I have to build the app in a special way with Android Studio or can
>   I simply use the delivered ApiDemo.apk for installation?

***Yes and No*** : You can simply use the delivered ApiDemo.apk but ensuring it is a debuggable build which would be helpful for you to get to know the details of the element you would be accessing while creating your automation suite.

> Do I have to launch the emulator or is Appium Inspector doing this for me?

***No*** : You wouldn't have to launch and emulator if you have specified the appropriate configurations of an AVD on appium GUI[which should be running as you execute your tests.]

*Note : Ideally you provide some capabilities to the appium server via your code and some of them are set by default on your GUI, a merged combination of these helps you drive your tests.*